# any interaction with UI in fragment beyond defenition causes app crash and an "Error creating fragment"

Tags: android, user-interface, onclick, runtime, fragment

I have been all over stackoverflow and a bunch of other sites for a few days full time and still wasn't able to resolve this.

I can define UI in fragment but cant interact with them like using `setText()` or handling clicks and each time i face runtime error and in the logcat :

> Error in creating fragment.

I've tried so many solutions that seemed to work for other people but still nothing! it would be really nice if you could help here is the code for fragment:

```
public class FragmentContact extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

Button btnSend;

public FragmentContact() {
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

// -----------------------------------------------
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);

    try {
         IToast toast = new IToast(getActivity(), inflater);
         btnSend = ((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSend));
        EditText etMail = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etMail);

        //causes error:
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
        //notice that i AM implementing onclicklistener!

        //also causes error:
        btnSend.setText("send");

    } catch (Exception x) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), x.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        return rootView;
    }

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onclick handled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .show();
}

}
```

and here is the code for main, where i call it:

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void displayView(int position) {

    android.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FragmentHome();
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    case 4:
        break;
    case 5:
        break;
    case 8://CONTACT_FRAGMENT---------------------------
        try{
        fragment = new FragmentContact();
        }catch(Exception x){
            toast.show(x.getMessage());
        }
        break;
        //----------------------------------------------
    case 9:
        fragment = new FragmentSuggest();
        break;
    case 10:
        Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),VoxReceiverAct.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case 11:

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        //fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left,
                //R.animator.slide_out_right);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Comment: post `fragment_contact.xml`

Comment: remove the try catch in Fragment and then run again. Extract the stacktrace from logcat and post it here.

Comment: thanks, java.lang.nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
btnSend = ((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSend));
```

Should be

```
btnSend = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSend));
```

cause the view belongs to the Fragment Layout.

Also it is better you remove the try catch in Fragment. You will know the cause by looking at the stacktrace. There is no need to display the exception in `Toast`.

Comment: thank you, done it, no difference, plus it was like that at the begining

Comment: @user3625457 without stacktrace it is hard for anyone to point further mistakes. There will be difference. post the stacktrace i guess you have new errors

Comment: @user3625457 That is one line. that is not enough. Post the full stacktrace. and frament layout

Comment: 05-11 17:39:14.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 17:39:14.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18298): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 17:39:14.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18298):  at imperium.imperium.imperium.FragmentContact.onCreateView(FragmentContact.java:40)
05-11 17:39:14.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18298):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:833)
05-11 17:39:14.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18298):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039)

Comment: 05-11 17:39:14.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18298):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:430)
05-11 17:39:14.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18298):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-11 17:39:14.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18298):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-11 17:39:14.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18298):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
05-11 17:39:14.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18298):

Comment: @user3625457 it would be better if you edit you post and post it there. Indicate Line 40 in `FragmentContact.java`. That is where you have the problem

Comment: @user3625457 if you are new to stackoverflow read the FAQ before posting the question.

Comment: yes im new. thanks for help. line 40 would be btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: post `fragment_contact.xml`. the suggestion by me looks right. any way post the xml layout to confirm

Comment: thank you for your time @Raghunandan , as you suggested there was a new error and it was in the xml and i was able to solve it. is there anyway i could give you a thumbs up in stackoverflow?;)